# Detect Language Text in PHP without huge dependences or third-party services

Tags: php, nlp, composer-php, language-detection

Looking for a composer package, which without a huge dependency (without knowledge bases more than 3MB) and third-party services will be able to determine the language of the text.

The text is very often consists of several words.

For example, I'd like to see this package with a high accuracy identified the languages of the following fragments:

1. > text on english
2. > Текст на русском
3. > Текст на русском и some words on english
4. > 結城友奈は勇者である -鷲尾須美の章- 第2章 「たましい」
5. > விவேகம்
6. > El aeropuerto se considera
7. > Wunderbar steht er da im Silberhaar.
8. > Ein weiß glänzendes
9. > si les faits n’obéissent pas
10. > 4 8 15 16 23 42

Mainly interested in the qualitative determination for the following languages: **English**, **Russian**, **German**, Spanish, Dutch, Italian, **French**, **Chinese**, **Japanese**, Norwegian, Danish, **Indian**.

A big plus would be if this package is not outdated or abandoned.

PS: It is important that they do not take much memory when running.

Comment: use this blog article and use library which they suggested.[http://phphtml.info/how-to-detect-language-for-a-string-in-php/](http://phphtml.info/how-to-detect-language-for-a-string-in-php/)

Comment: @Gaurav, thanks for the link. I checked the package and it did not come to me. See please my answer to this question below.

Comment: NB that OP is only interested in PHP-based solutions, but this isn't clearly stated in the question (other than a PHP tag).

Answer (score 1):

I test PHP-package [Text_LanguageDetect](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_LanguageDetect) with my examples and some other tests and I am disappointed with the results...

```
require_once('libs/languagedetect/Text/LanguageDetect.php');
$l = new Text_LanguageDetect();
$l->setNameMode(2);
```

1.

```
$l->detect('text on english', 4); // BAD
=> [
 "nl" => 0.244,
 "fi" => 0.23111111111111,
 "sq" => 0.21933333333333,
 "et" => 0.21333333333333,
]
```

2.

```
$l->detect('Текст на русском', 4); // OK
=> [
 "ru" => 0.36770833333333,
 "sr" => 0.30083333333333,
 "bg" => 0.29145833333333,
 "uk" => 0.22354166666667,
]
```

3.

```
$l->detect('Текст на русском и some words on english', 4); // ???
=> [
 "ru" => 0.17625,
 "sr" => 0.14675,
 "" => 0.14608333333333,
 "bg" => 0.14341666666667,
]
```

4.

```
$l->detect('結城友奈は勇者である -鷲尾須美の章- 第2章 「たましい」', 4); // BAD
=> []
```

5.

```
$l->detect('விவேகம்', 4);  // BAD
=> []
```

6.

```
$l->detect('El aeropuerto se considera', 4); // OK
=> [
 "es" => 0.49410256410256,
 "pt" => 0.32576923076923,
 "it" => 0.30230769230769,
 "fr" => 0.25333333333333,
]
```

7.

```
$l->detect('Wunderbar steht er da im Silberhaar.', 4); // OK
=> [
 "de" => 0.39235294117647,
 "da" => 0.34078431372549,
 "sv" => 0.31029411764706,
 "no" => 0.30147058823529,
]
```

8.

```
$l->detect('Ein weiß glänzendes', 4);  // OK
=> [
 "de" => 0.43947368421053,
 "nl" => 0.2259649122807,
 "cy" => 0.17456140350877,
 "fr" => 0.17070175438596,
]
```

9.

```
$l->detect('si les faits n’obéissent pas', 4);  // OK
=> [
 "fr" => 0.37595238095238,
 "pt" => 0.23869047619048,
 "la" => 0.22880952380952,
 "de" => 0.20511904761905,
]
```

10.

```
$l->detect('4 8 15 16 23 42', 4); // OK
=> []
```

11.

```
$l->detect('accuracy identified', 4); // BAD
=> [
 "la" => 0.19368421052632,
 "no" => 0.14491228070175,
 "es" => 0.13491228070175,
 "ro" => 0.13157894736842,
]
```

12.

```
$l->detect('big text', 4); // BAD
=> [
 "is" => 0.32708333333333,
 "tl" => 0.21208333333333,
 "nl" => 0.205,
 "vi" => 0.20458333333333,
]
```

13.

```
$l->detect('very long text is ok', 4); // OK
=> [
 "en" => 0.29383333333333,
 "nl" => 0.26883333333333,
 "tl" => 0.20583333333333,
 "hu" => 0.182,
]
```

14.

```
$l->detect('symbols', 4); // BAD
=> [
 "de" => 0.068095238095238,
 "nl" => 0.049523809523809,
 "sw" => 0.044285714285714,
 "pl" => 0.040952380952381,
]
```

15.

```
$l->detect('language', 4); // BAD
=> [
 "da" => 0.34875,
 "tl" => 0.33458333333333,
 "" => 0.33416666666667,
 "id" => 0.28291666666667,
]
```

I'm really very disappointed that such an old and seemingly time - tested package is not working as it should.

I have a lot of checks with short words, which need to identify what they are in English (or at least give the possibility that they are on it). Because you will come across characters and other special characters.

Very convenient that the package displays the list of languages - I could check in 4 language as in the example. But I doubt that there will be false positives. So I don't dare to use it.

**Please advise other solution on PHP.** It would be incorrect to run from php a different process for checking the language.

Comment: I also checked out package: https://packagist.org/packages/ideea/language-detector and got similar results

Comment: I found the package: https://packagist.org/packages/patrickschur/language-detection , he gives results a little better, but it was originally stipulated that he can learn on the source files. I think that after weekend will try to retrain and test the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of libraries that can do language detection that I'm aware of:

- [langid.py](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py) (Python)
- [language-detection](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection) (Java)
- [Chromium language detector](https://github.com/mikemccand/chromium-compact-language-detector) (C++)
- [Language-detector](https://github.com/optimaize/language-detector) (Java)
- [Apache Tika's Language Detector](https://tika.apache.org/1.14/detection.html) (Java)

None of these require the use of a third-party service, but the performance of most solutions is pretty heavily dependent on the length of the input test - YMMV... But most of them can do dozens of languages, so you should be covered, in theory - and if not, most allow you to train your own model.

Comment: Sorry, but I need solution in php

Comment: If you're using PHP, that probably means you are running some kind of web service. If there isn't something equally performing in PHP as the packages I suggested, wouldn't it make more sense to interface with some tried and tested solution using a web API, or Thrift, or as an PHP extension/bridge? Also, in my experience, the best way to implement a language detection service is to use at least three different approaches and [boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) them.